# how to call checkbox from other class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a textbox in a class called TransportJobs.aspx and a checkbox in another class called CompanyDetails.aspx.

```
chkJobsDocketRReq.Checked = Company.Current.GetModule("Jobs").DocketReq;
```

I want to called the checkbox in the TransJobs class so I can check if it has been ticked or not.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDocketNo.Text))
        {
            if (chkJobsDocketRReq.Checked) //error
            {
                Valid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Valid = false;
                txtDocketNo.Style.Add("background-color", "#FCF");
                txtDocketNo.Style.Add("background-image", "none");
                throw new FormatException("Docket No");
            }
        }
```

So since chkJobsDocketRReq belongs to a different class, how can I call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `chkJobsDocketRReq` is a control on your page then you can access it using FindControl assuming all is on the same page

```
var chkJobsDocketRReq = (CheckBox)this.FindControl("name_of_control");
If (chkJobsDocketRReq.Checked) {}
```

Comment: the code for checkbox on the page is `chkJobsDocketRReq.Checked = Company.Current.GetModule("Jobs").DocketReq;`

Comment: Ok so they two different pages, how do you navigate between the pages. You would either post from one to the other in which case you can use `Request.Form` or you will need to pass the value on the query string `CompanyDetails.aspx?chk=??`